# How to move data from one store to another in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

When upgrading database I want to move some data from one store to another. But I'm not able to do like this:

```
    import { openDB } from 'idb';

    const testVersion = 2;
    const db = await openDB('Profile', testVersion, {
      upgrade: async (db, oldVersion, newVersion) => {
        if (newVersion === 1) {
          db.createObjectStore(username);
        } else if (newVersion === 2) {
          db.createObjectStore('profileImage');
          try {
            const storedInPreviousVersion = await db.get(
              username,
              'profileImage'
            );
          await db.put('profileImage', storedInPreviousVersion, username);
          db.deleteObjectStore(username);
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('Did not find old store', e);
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

It seems to be impossible to get a value within an upgrade. Is there any way around this limitation?

Comment: Do not use await within the upgrade needed event handler because this will not work. That introduces a yield that allows the upgrade transaction to complete. The put request has to happen in the same tick as the get request from within the handler.